# What method should I use for comparing the similarity between variables

Tags: correlation, clustering, python, similarities, hierarchical-clustering

#### Background

I'm investigating the performance of air quality monitoring sites. In one city, several sites will compose a whole network for detecting the temporal variation of air pollutants. I want to compare the similarity from the information captured by each site.

#### Case

Suppose there are 7 sites located in the study area of interest. Each site has a time-series data for certain species. I have already created a panda.Dataframe and use pearson coefficient to compare their similarity. If the r value are high for certain data-paris, it indicated that the information they captured are redundant. Then, I want to use cluster analysis and divide the sites into several clusters. Then I can compare the similar-site-paris individually by some other indexes and the one with weak performance will be eliminated.

The datafile I uploade [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7FE0kxAL8kQeG40bEthM0U0YVU/view?usp=sharing), anyone interested can download it.

#### Problem

With different linkage method, the cluster results seems to be different.  They are less useful considering of my initial idea.

#### My code

The code I wrote here can illustrate my results.

```
#### The plotting code are copied from 
##http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982929/plotting-results-of-hierarchical-clustering-ontop-of-a-matrix-of-data-in-python  

import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import pylab

df = pd.read_csv("corr-no2.txt")

D = scipy.zeros([7,7])
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(7):
        D[i,j] = df.iloc[:,i].corr(df.iloc[:,j])
print D[2,2] 

# Compute and plot first dendrogram.
fig = pylab.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.09,0.1,0.2,0.6])
Y = sch.linkage(D, method='average')
Z1 = sch.dendrogram(Y, orientation='right')#,above_threshold_color='b')
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])

# Compute and plot second dendrogram.
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.3,0.71,0.6,0.2])
Y = sch.linkage(D, method='centroid')
Z2 = sch.dendrogram(Y)
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])

# Plot distance matrix.
axmatrix = fig.add_axes([0.3,0.1,0.6,0.6])
idx1 = Z1['leaves']
idx2 = Z2['leaves']
D = D[idx1,:]
D = D[:,idx2]
im = axmatrix.matshow(D, aspect='auto', origin='lower', cmap=pylab.cm.YlGnBu)

site_name = list(df.columns)
axmatrix.set_xticks(range(7))
site_X = [ site_name[i] for i in idx1]
axmatrix.set_xticklabels(site_X, minor=False)
axmatrix.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom')
axmatrix.xaxis.tick_bottom()
pylab.xticks( fontsize=12)

axmatrix.set_yticks(range(7))
site_Y = [ site_name[i] for i in idx2]
axmatrix.set_yticklabels(site_Y, minor=False)
axmatrix.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
axmatrix.yaxis.tick_right()
pylab.yticks(fontsize=12)

pylab.show()
```

[image]

I use `average` and `centroid` method. And I found out some site-pair with strong correlation relation are not merged together as a cluster.

For example: df.iloc[:,6].corr(df.iloc[:,5]) ==  0.83, But their corresponding sites are not in the same cluster.

If anyone are familiar with the similarity analysis, I would appreciate that you offer some advices!

#### PS

If I want to add another indexes here (e.g, the mean value for each sites), how to add this feature into similarity analysis alongside $r$?